# How to create a new window in gdb that would display stack contents?

Tags: linux, gdb

Currently i have the gdb layout with cmd,registers and asm. Is there any way i can add a new window/view which always shows the contents of the stack? 
For example create a window which would display the output of gdb command "x/20x $rsp"

This would be really useful while debugging.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any way to create a window with the stack. But you can always `display/20xw $rsp` as a poor man's substitute.

Comment: display would always be an option. yes :(

Comment: Maybe it goes without saying; but in addition to the TUI there are many GUIs available, and I think they all have stack views.